# How update TTL in cassandra using Achilles and throw an exception if it does not exist

Tags: cql, cassandra-2.0

I want to update the TTL of an object in Cassandra using Achilles; but if the object does not exist, an exception should be thrown. I would like to do this in one operation to Cassandra making use of LWT.

I tried the following

```
DO do = asyncManager.forUpdate(DO.class, "not found");
OptionsBuilder.BuiltOptions options = OptionsBuilder.withTtl(5);
options.ifEqualCondition(MappingDO.TYPE_FIELD, "0");

try {
    asyncManager.update(do, options).get(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
    // An LWT exception should be caught here since the object does not exist
}
```

Since the object does not exist; I would expect the conditional update to fail. But instead the operation does not fail.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the conditional update to work; a column must be updated.

On the object 'do', at least one other property beside the key must be specified. The value does not have to be different from what already exists.